# SQL Bulk Delete Queries on composite key with fixed length query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

In Postgresql, I've a table that has a composite primary key.
`PRIMARY KEY(id_fnd_users, id_app_apps,id_app_categories)`

I'm trying to create a query to do a bulk delete and I want this query to be fixed size (for stat analysis purpose).

This is what I came up with :

```
 DELETE FROM app_users_apps_categories
 WHERE
   ("id_fnd_users", "id_app_apps","id_app_categories") 
   in (
          SELECT id_fnd_users, id_app_apps, id_app_categories
          FROM unnest($1::"uuid"[], $2::"uuid"[], $3::"uuid"[]) AS foo(id_fnd_users, id_app_apps,id_app_categories)
        )
```

and here are an example of the parameters I set for this query:

```
$1 = '{61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c,61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c}',
$2 = '{25fda4e9-ca83-41fb-98ad-77230a74bbbc,34c0cd50-905e-4ea6-9ccf-baeaa591e98a}', 
$3 = '{NULL,NULL}'
```

Basically I'm ending up with a query like this :

```
DELETE FROM app_users_apps_categories
        where ("id_fnd_users", "id_app_apps","id_app_categories") in (
          SELECT id_fnd_users, id_app_apps, id_app_categories
          FROM 
            unnest(
                '{61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c,61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c}'::"uuid"[], 
                '{25fda4e9-ca83-41fb-98ad-77230a74bbbc,34c0cd50-905e-4ea6-9ccf-baeaa591e98a}'::"uuid"[], 
                '{NULL,NULL}'::"uuid"[]
             ) AS foo(id_fnd_users, id_app_apps,id_app_categories)
      )
```

The query is executed correctly but my record are not deleted.
I've checked the IDs and their order and they are OK.
So I guess that's not the proper way of doing this but I can't figure out another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you passing your parameters $1,$2,$3. But I guess that doesn't really matter. Your problem seems to with NULL value. No matter how you arrive at the comparison null-to-null always produces null and no equal (or here IN) will ever match. As with any other data type you can use coalesce with UUIDs. So

```
delete 
  from app_users_apps_categories
 where (id_fnd_users
       ,id_app_apps
       ,coalesce(id_app_categories,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)
       )                             
   in (
        select id_fnd_users
             , id_app_apps
             , coalesce(id_app_categories,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) 
          from 
               unnest(
                       '{61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c,61615807-c654-4844-910c-1609dcf3ff4c}'::uuid[], 
                       '{25fda4e9-ca83-41fb-98ad-77230a74bbbc,34c0cd50-905e-4ea6-9ccf-baeaa591e98a}'::uuid[], 
                       '{null,null}'::uuid[]
                     ) as foo(id_fnd_users, id_app_apps,id_app_categories)  
       ) ;
```

You can also wrap this in a SQL function returning void:

```
create or replace function remove_app_users_apps_categories(
                           fnd_users_in uuid[]
                         , app_apps_in  uuid[]
                         , app_cats_in  uuid[]
                         )
  returns void
  language sql 
as $$
delete 
  from app_users_apps_categories
 where (id_fnd_users
       ,id_app_apps
       ,coalesce(id_app_categories,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid)
       )                             
   in (
        select id_fnd_users
             , id_app_apps
             , coalesce(id_app_categories,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid) 
          from 
               unnest( fnd_users_in
                     , app_apps_in 
                     , app_cats_in 
                     ) as foo(id_fnd_users, id_app_apps,id_app_categories)  
       ) ; 
$$;
```

Just my quirkiness I guess but I never use the $n notation. Can't remember what n means what.